# Change page size by adding a white area in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: adobe, acrobat

My pdf size is 11.68 inch by 8.26 inch. I want to transform it into a pdf of size 12.39 inch (=8.26*1.5) by 8.26 inch to get a 1.5 ratio. In addition, I want to keep the same size of the figure and thus, only create a white space on the bottom of the page to get the right dimension (see figure).

[image: Illustration of what I want]

Comment: What API were you thinking of using? You could do this with JavaScript and an Acrobat Action if you are using the DC Pro version.

Comment: I was just thinking of using Adobe Acrobat Pro..

Comment: ... and JavaScript?